# map multiply tables to single entity in entity framework code first

Tags: entity-framework

In the database we have tables called Sites, Organisations, Person, Department have the same structure like LookupID, Description etc. 
and there are some other tables like Question, Answer etc. These tables have same columns as above with two or three extra columns.

What is best way to implement this using Entity Framework Code-First.

In the code side I was thinking LookUp Class with common Properties and then some more properties for Question etc.

I can not think how i will be able to tell EF to load the lookup I want, because (I cannot have the type as Site, Organisation etc, because these are all lookups etc.

Version is not problem we can use the latest one available as this is new project.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like Table-per-class (TPC) inheritance. You will model your Lookup entity as base abstract class and derive all other entities from the Lookup entity. Derived classes will declare only specific fields. In database each derived entity will be represented as separete table with both shared and derived fields.

It is possible to achieve this mapping in [database first (EDMX)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/01/25/table-per-concrete-type-inheritance-in-entity-framework.aspx) and [code first](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/01/03/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines.aspx) approach but it can have some performance implications when you try to query those tables. If you query just general lookup EF will always joins all your derived tables because it doesn't know which contains specific fields you need. I'm not sure if this happens in TPC inheritance as well but EF sometimes joined all inherited tables even if you explicitly tell it that you want to query specific type - this was especially problem in other form of inheritance (TPT) but it should be solved in .NET 4.5.

Edit: There is one detail I forgot to mention. Each entity in EF must be uniquely identified by its key. If you map inheritance each entity in inheritance hierarchy must be uniquely identified by its key. It means that all your lookup tables must use unique key values.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I can not think how i will be able to tell EF to load the lookup I want, because (I cannot have the type as Site, Organisation etc, because these are all lookups etc.

Comment: No they are not just lookups. They have specific fields - you must still differ among them. Otherwise you must create single view containing union of all of them with all possible columns. Specific columns for one table will be empty in records for other tables.

Comment: Thanks, should I create a property like type with string value and should not be mapped to database, is it is possible. Is there any example etc. Thanks very much for help

Comment: With original approach using inheritance you usually don't need such property because each entity has specific .NET type. In the second approach with view you must put that as computed column directly to the view and map it.

Comment: thanks for great advice, if I want to create type for each lookup, can I create type without any properties. i.e. Lookup(base type) has LookUpID, description properties, but Site inherit from LookUp with no additional properties. Thanks for help and guide me.

Comment: If it maps to its own table you have to create separate type.